Playwright automation exception - Page.LocatorOptions().setHasText() giving 2 elements. How to identify uniquely
I am trying to select a value from an Angular dropdown using Playwright-Java. It is failing due to multiple values found. How to uniquely identify by text.
    getPage().locator(obj).click();

    Locator list = getPage().locator("//span[@class='mat-option-text']", new Page.LocatorOptions().setHasText(value));

    list.click();

Exception: com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
message='Error: strict mode violation: locator("//span[@class='mat-option-text']").filter(new Locator.FilterOptions().setHasText("Corporation")) resolved to 2 elements:


https://playwright.dev/java/docs/locators#locate-by-text. XPath is discouraged.

Is the .setExact(true) available to ensure it matches only 'Corporation'?

@ggorlen - .setExact(true) is not supported for Page.LocatorOptions()

@AutomationAndy - setExact(true) is not supported for Page.LocatorOptions() method. setExact(true) is for Page.GetByTextOptions()

If you want to use CSS selectors - you can use first()
   page.locator(".mat-option-text", { hasText: "Corporation" }).first()

Another option getByText or getByRole - exact can help
   page.getByRole("option", { name: "Corporation", exact: true })
   // or
   page.getByText("Corporation", { exact: true })

or in Java
   page.getByText("Corporation", new Page.GetByTextOptions().setExact(true)


I was able to solve the issue by looping through all the list of elements and putting condition on the expected element.
